# JavaScript only working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

After field validation, the code below is not returning any values of the previous page. But this code is only working in Chrome. Firefox and IE are not working.

```
function quickenquiryValidator() {
    // Make quick references to our fields
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
    var qename = document.getElementById('qename');
    var qemobile = document.getElementById('qemobile');
    var qeemail = document.getElementById('qeemail');
    var calculation = document.getElementById('BotBootInput_Enquiry').value;
    // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
    //if(isAlphabet(qename, "Please enter only letters for your name")){
    if (regex.test(qename.value)) {
        if (isNumeric(qemobile, "Please enter a valid mobile number")) {
            if (emailValidator(qeemail, "Please enter a valid email address")) {
                if (check_calculation(calculation, "Please enter valid calculation result")) {
                    document.getElementById("submit4").setAttribute("type", "submit");
                    document.quickenqform.submit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter only letters for your name");
        qename.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Well, there are some branches in your if statements, that don't return any result (when condition is not fulfilled). Is it possible, that one of those branches executes?

Comment: can you localize the problem in fiddle ?

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: In Firefox: have you tried stepping through with a debugger like Firebug?